# Delete duplicates and update the one unique left all in one statement?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, sql-update

```sql
CREATE TABLE hostname_table
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
hostname CHAR(65) NOT NULL,
interval_avg INT,
last_update DATETIME NOT NULL,
numb_updates INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I have this table, and I import 500-600k rows of data into it. I do not check for duplicates when writing to the database, because I want to know how many duplicates of each host there is, and I also want to know the intervals between each update of said hostname.

Example values in hostname_table:

```
id  hostname          interval_avg  last_update          numb_updates
1   www.host.com      60            2012-04-25 20:22:21  1
2   www.hostname.com  10            2012-04-25 20:22:21  5
3   www.name.com      NULL          2012-04-25 20:22:21  NULL
4   www.host.com      NULL          2012-04-25 20:22:26  NULL
5   www.host.com      NULL          2012-04-25 20:22:36  NULL
```

Example of what I want it to look like when I have cleaned it up:

```
id  hostname          interval_avg  last_update          numb_updates
1   www.host.com      25            2012-04-25 20:22:36  3
2   www.hostname.com  10            2012-04-25 20:22:21  5
3   www.name.com      NULL          2012-04-25 20:22:21  NULL
```

With a huge database like this, I dont want to send too many queries to obtain this goal, but I believe 3 queries are the minimum for an operation like this(if I am wrong, please correct me). Each hour there will be ~500k new rows where ~50% or more will be duplicates, therefore its vital to get rid of those duplicates as efficiently as possible while still keeping a record of how many and how often the duplicates occured(hense the interval_avg and numb_update update).

This is a three step problem, and I was hoping the community here would give a helping hand.

## So to summarize in pseudocode, I need help optimizing these queries;

1. **select** all last_update and interval_avg values, get sum(numb_update), get count(duplicates) foreach hostname,
2. **update** interval_avg in min(id), update numb_updates in min(id), update last_update in min(id) with the value from max(id),
3. **delete** all duplicates except min(id)

[SOLVED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10338807/1248273).
I have optimized one part by 94%, and another part by ~97% over the course of a couple of days researching. I truely hope this will help other searching for the same solutions. mySQL and large databases can be a big problem if you choose the wrong solution.
(I changed the last_update column from DATETIME to INT(10), and I changed from a formated time to a timestamp as value in my final solution to be able to get the max(last_update) and min(last_update) values)

*(Thanks to GolezTrol for helping with parts of the problem)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get each different value of interval_avg and numb_updates for a hostname if you want to aggregate by that hostname. Did you mean to `SUM` or maybe `AVG` them? Or do you just want to keep the value of the lowest id?

In the query below I sum them.

```
SELECT 
  MIN(id) as id, 
  hostname, 
  SUM(interval_avg) as total_interval_avg,
  SUM(numb_updates) as total_numb_updates,
  COUNT(*) as hostname_count
FROM
  hostname_table
GROUP BY 
  hostname
```

After this, you will need to update each found id with the right values for `interval_avg` and `numb_updates`.

After that, you will need to delete each id that is not found by this query.

```
DELETE FROM hostname_table
WHERE
  id NOT IN
    (SELECT 
      MIN(id)
    FROM
      hostname_table
    GROUP BY 
      hostname)
```

Comment: @GolezTrol: The `DELETE` statement may not be very efficent. I think MySQL does not perform very well when you have subqueries in the `WHERE` of a Delete statement. It will probably be more efficient to move the derived subquery into a Join.

Comment: @ypercube And how do you join in a delete?

Comment: @turbopipp It's not entirely clear what you need for interval_avg, but it looks like you need to recalculate the avarage, so you may either need `AVG(interval_avg)` or even `AVG(interval_avg * numb_updates)`.

Comment: @GolezTrol I added example values in my question now, hopefully that will clarify what I try to achieve. :) Thanks for all your help thus far!

Answer (score 0):

## I went with this solution

## --------------------------------

**1.select** all min+max last_update, sum(interval_avg), sum(numb_update) and count(duplicates) foreach hostname

```php
//This will get the interval_avg value
//(summarize is ok, since all except min(id) will be zero), 
//give a count of how many duplicates there are per hostname, 
//and will also summarize numb_updates
SELECT 
  MIN(id) as id, 
  hostname, 
  SUM(numb_updates) as total_numb_updates,
  SUM(interval_avg) as total_interval_avg,
  MAX(last_update) as last_update_max,
  MIN(last_update) as last_update_min,
  COUNT(*) as hostname_count
FROM
  hostname_table
GROUP BY 
  hostname
HAVING 
  COUNT(*)>1
```

```php
//Get all last_update from each duplicate hostname(including the original)
//Dont do this in a seperate query, you only need first+last+rowcount to figure
//out the interval average. It took me a while to realize this, so I tried many
//varieties with little success(took too long with +600k rows) 
//
// --- I will include the solution I didn't go for, ---
// --- so others wont do the same mistake ---
//
// START DONT USE THIS
// 2.63sec @ 10000 rows
$sql = "SELECT
  id, 
  ".$db_table.".hostname, 
  last_update 
FROM 
  ".$db_table." 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    hostname, 
    COUNT(*) 
  FROM 
    ".$db_table." 
  GROUP BY 
    hostname 
  HAVING 
    COUNT(*)>1
) as t2
ON 
  ".$db_table.".hostname = t2.hostname";

$resource = mysql_query($sql,$con);
// END DONT USE THIS (below is a 94% improvement)
//
// START THIS IS BETTER, BUT DONT USE THIS
// 0.16 sec @ 10000 rows
//Select everything from the table
$sql = "SELECT id 
    FROM ".$db_table;
$resource = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$array_id_all = array();
while($assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)){
    array_push($array_id_all, $assoc['id']);
}

//This will select the ID of all the hosts without duplicates
$sql = "SELECT 
  MIN(id) as id, 
  hostname
FROM
  ".$db_table."
GROUP BY 
  hostname
HAVING 
  COUNT(*)=1";

$resource = mysql_query($sql,$con);

$array_id_unique = array();
while($assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)){
    array_push($array_id_unique, $assoc['id']);
}

$array_id_non_unique = array_diff($array_id_all, $array_id_unique);
$id_list_non_unique = implode(", ", $array_id_non_unique);

//Select everything from the table when the IDs are IN $id_list_non_unique
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM ".$db_table." 
    WHERE id IN (".$id_list_non_unique.")";
$resource = mysql_query($sql,$con);

$array_duplicates = array();
$i=0;
while($assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)){
    $array_duplicates[$i] = array($assoc['id'], $assoc['hostname'], $assoc['interval_avg'], $assoc['last_update'], $assoc['numb_updates']);
    $i++;
}
// END THIS IS BETTER, BUT DONT USE THIS
```

*(thanks to Nick Fortescue @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/877051/1248273)*

**2.update** interval_avg in min(id), update numb_updates in min(id), update last_update in min(id) with the value from max(id)

```php
//update the interval_avg, last_update and numb_update value of the min(id)
//of each duplicate hostname.
// --- I will include the solution I didn't go for, ---
// --- so others wont do the same mistake ---
//
// START DONT USE THIS
// 167 secs @ 500k rows
UPDATE hostname_table
  SET interval_avg = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 25
    //etc
  END,
  last_update = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN "2012-04-25 20:22:36"
    //etc
  END,
  numb_update = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 3
    //etc
  END
WHERE id IN (1)
// END DONT USE THIS
//
// START USE THIS
// 5.75 secs @ 500k rows (96.6% improvement)
INSERT INTO hostname_table (id,interval_avg,last_update,numb_updates)
  VALUES 
    ('1','25','2012-04-25 20:22:36','3'), 
    //etc
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  interval_avg=VALUES(interval_avg), 
  last_update=VALUES(last_update), 
  numb_updates=VALUES(numb_updates)
// END USE THIS
```

*(thanks to Michiel de Mare @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466/1248273)*

**3.delete** all duplicates except min(id)

```sql
//delete all duplicates except min(id)
ALTER IGNORE TABLE hostname_table ADD UNIQUE (hostname)
ALTER TABLE hostname_table DROP INDEX hostname
```

*(thanks to GolezTrol for a good push in the right direction on selecting the first info I needed)*