# Finding averages timestamp based on two rows

Tags: mysql

Basically i'm attempting to get an average based on two time stamps inside a database, let's say for example i have a product, I insert it into the database **10 times** with an `listed_time` and a `sell_time`, I want to group all **10 rows** together and find the average between both the `listed_time` and the `sell_time` to find on average on how long it took to sell.

**EDIT** : timestamps are inserted as `time()` not `date()`

The code in which i tried and failed to work was

```
$query = $db->runSQL("SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, listed_time, sell_time)) from trade");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, listed_time, sell_time))']."</br>";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to find the average time difference between rows in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876842/how-to-find-the-average-time-difference-between-rows-in-a-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for that 10 rows:

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, listed_time, sell_time ) ) as za_avg ...
```

This will give you the average time (for those 10 rows) it took to sell the items

Comment: can you pls tell me why it failed? was there a error? or the output wasn't the one desired?

Comment: i have added the code i used to my initial question, it didn't echo anything

Comment: I've added an alias so try `echo $row['za_avg']."</br>";` and see what the output is